# How to make Laravel Splade submit form on Enter and not "click" cancel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10, laravel-vue

I have a form with a cancel and Submit button:

```
            <Link href="{{ route('admin.suppliers.show', $supplier->id) }}">
            <x-button color="gray">Cancel</x-button>
            </Link>
            <x-splade-submit label="Save" />
```

When the user presses ENTER, the "Cancel" button is "clicked".  I expect the form to be submitted.

If I remove the "Link" or make it a standard "a" tag, it behaves as expected.

Is there a way to still use the "Link" but not have it be the default action?